# compile mapbox-gl with webpack takes long time

Tags: webpack, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to compile the simple mapbox-gl example with webpack.
I'm using webpack with the following standard configuration:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    watch: true,
    output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
};
```

My `main.js` is the example from the mapbox-gl site:

```
var mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js');
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'ACCESS_TOKEN';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
   container: 'map',
   style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
});
```

Each change in the main.js file triggers recompilation of everything which takes about 10 seconds.
Is there simple way to improve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. this was simple. I've just need to add the mode: 'development'.